# Facebook page source with Python or Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a few hundred Facebook users names (not friends) and would like to get those people's Facebook user id or personal URL link.

Manually I can search by name or type this link (https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=Wilhelem%20Gabriella) and click on the name or profile picture and I go the that person's profile page and I simply copy the URL (https://www.facebook.com/gabriella.wilhelem).

I have been trying to automate this process with Python, Beautiful soup. However, Facebook uses tons of hidden elements and my programming knowledge was not enough for this job.

So I tried to download the whole webpage source code and then work with those files locally later on. I am working with following code. This works with http sites, but I can't make it work with my Facebook link.

Since I have little programming knowledge, I will appreciate if anyone can help me finish this code instead of just suggesting me to use headless browser and so on.

```
import urllib

# file where it will be stored to
rawSrc='C:\Users\JH\Desktop\webpages.txt';
linkSrc='C:\Users\JH\Desktop\links.txt';

# this function will download the source code and save it as a txt file.
def dlSrc():
    # Open first file where source code will be saved
    wRawSrc=open(rawSrc,'w')
    # connect and donwnload
    locPage='https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=Wilhelem%20Gabriella';
    webPage=urllib.urlopen(locPage)
    wPageSrc=webPage.read()
    webPage.close()
    # write to text file
    wRawSrc.write(wPageSrc)

# this function will extract all the links and save them on another txt file
def cleanFile():
    # open raw HTML source for reading
    rRawSrc=open(rawSrc,'r')
    # open the stripped one for writing
    wlinkSrc=open(linkSrc,'w')
    # export only the lines that contain &quot;a href&quot;
    for line in rRawSrc:
        if 'a href' in line:
            wlinkSrc.write(line)

# Run the functions
dlSrc()
cleanFile()
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php What you're trying to do is against FB's policies.

Comment: what tobi said. it is not allowed, so dont do it. what would you even do with the IDs/data? you are not allowed to store or use them in any way either, without specific authorization of the users.

Comment: All I am wondering is it possible?  if possible what method should do the trick?